# Visual Studio Code (flutter) doesn't show full error stack trace

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, stack-trace

I'm developing a flutter app in VS code. In visual studio code when there is an error it just says which widget caused an error but doesn't tell which line inside the widget caused it. I checked it in android studio, it works fine there. I found this GitHub thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67418. But it's for Android Studio so the solution of downgrading the flutter plugin in android studio doesn't work for me.

**VISUAL STUDIO CODE**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Invalid argument(s)
The relevant error-causing widget was
TagList
lib\page\LikePage.dart:86
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**ANDROID STUDIO**

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown building TagList(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<RecomProvider>], state: _TagListState#79f23):
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TagList file:///C:/development/scratch/lib/page/LikePage.dart:86:37
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      _TagListState.build (package:scratch/widget/TagList.dart:24:35)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
```

As you see Android studio has:
**When the exception was thrown, this was the stack**

But visual studio code doesn't have it.

Comment: vscode has it too: check https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging and find `DEBUG CONSOLE`

Comment: the caught exception I wrote above is from debug console of vs code. Or by saying debug console you mean something else?

Comment: so yes I understood correcty, as I said the error trace is from vs code debug console and it doesn't have "When the exception was thrown, this was the stack" only ═ Exception caught by widgets library. 
VS CODE: https://pasteboard.co/Kb25iVp.png
Android Stduio: https://pasteboard.co/Kb25B2f.png

Comment: what do you see if you run your app directly from the terminal window: `flutter -d <your device id> -v run`?

Comment: I think I found the issue, when I do in vs code (or in terminal as you said) it only shows full stack trace for 1 exception. for others it doesn't do that. In case od terminal it even just was saying:

[  +17 ms]
           Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
[   +1 ms]
           Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

not even showing line. or file where it occurred. 

something like this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16510

Comment: the problem is that it's not like related issues, so we cant say that we have 1 root cause and others arent important you should solve the first one at first.  i guess flutter somehow interprets them as 1 root and other sequent errors but that's not the case in my situation. They even are different widgets, I mean error causing widgets.

Comment: So this is what it shows in android studio: https://justpaste.it/446ki
and its in terminal: https://justpaste.it/6maxg. As you see in terminal all errors after 1 one are replaced with another error was thrown

Comment: @pskink ps i forgot to mention tour name